# Attempt to read property "puroks" on null

Tags: laravel

This code displays the respondent infected with the diseases and date ranges from the selected dropdowns, I want to display the household where that respondent belongs to and the purok which the household belongs to.

But when I tried to access the purok it says Attempt to read property "puroks" on null.

**View**

```
@foreach($infectedRespondents as $household)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $household->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $household->household->puroks->purok_num }}</td>
        <td>{{ $household->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
public function getInfected(Request $request)
{
    $SDOHs = SDOH::all();
    $categories = SDOHCategory::all();
    $HDs = HD::all();
    $diseases = Disease::all();
    $vaccines = Vaccine::all();
    $envHazards = EnvHazard::all();
    $puroks = Purok::all();
    $households = HouseholdHead::with('categoryHouseholds.sdoh_category')->get();
    $respondents = Respondent::with('household_heads')->get();
    $selectedDiseaseId = $request->input('disease');
    $startDate = $request->input('start');
    $endDate = $request->input('end');

    $infectedRespondents = Respondent::whereHas('diseases',
        function ($query) use ($selectedDiseaseId, $startDate, $endDate) {
            $query->where('disease_id', $selectedDiseaseId)
                ->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
        })
        ->with(['household_heads.puroks'])
        ->get();

    return view('filtered_map',
        compact('households', 'SDOHs', 'categories', 'diseases', 'vaccines', 'envHazards', 'respondents', 'puroks',
            'HDs', 'infectedRespondents'));
}
```

household_heads table has purok_id column reference to puroks table. respondents table and household_heads table have pivot table such as respondent_households table with respondent_id and household_head_id foreign keys.

I am new to Laravel which is why eloquent and pivot tables are still confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

When using PHP 8.0 or later versions, the nullsafe operator (?->) helps prevent 'trying to get property of non-object' errors when accessing properties or methods on potentially null objects.

In your Blade template, you can use the nullsafe operator as follows:

```
@foreach($infectedRespondents as $respondent)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $respondent->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $respondent->household_heads?->puroks?->purok_num }}</td>
        <td>{{ $respondent->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This usage allows for safe navigation through potentially null relationships. If any part of the chain (household_heads or puroks) is null, it gracefully returns null instead of throwing an error.

You can use optional() in Laravel with PHP versions 7.3 and newer.

```
@foreach($infectedRespondents as $respondent)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $respondent->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ optional(optional($respondent->household_heads)->puroks)->purok_num }}</td>
        <td>{{ $respondent->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

First `optional()` or `?->`: Checks if $respondent->household_heads is null.
If not null, it accesses ->puroks; if null, it returns null.

Second `optional()` or `?->`: Checks if the result of the first `optional() or ?->` is null.
If not null, it accesses ->purok_name; if null, it returns null.

Comment: it returns null, and I don't know why

Comment: @BigBrother  If puroks is not defined for a household_heads, it returns null